How do I maintain Bezier circle resolution when selecting fill mode "none" for processing with Geometry Nodes?
I have some (2D) Bezier circles (with resolution > 1) that I am transforming into nice smooth objects with a GeoNode stack:

Fillet Curve (poly, as Bezier creates a ton more vertices and ruins the Bevel modifier)
Fill Curve (which is why I am asking about fill mode "none" on the curve itself; selecting n-gons again or it ruins the Bevel modifier)
Extrude Mesh (Faces, nothing interesting) + Transform geometry on a duplicate (to create a mirror image to get a shape that's closed on both sides)
Join Geometry + Set Material

...and that all is then followed up by a Bevel modifier (Edges mode, again, nothing interesting). Here is all that in image form:

Also, the curve itself:

Now the problem is that with Fill Mode "none" on the curve I get "vector-type handle" behavior, i.e., the curve as if it had resolution 1:

If I set fill mode to, say, "both", I get the resolution back, but now my GeoNodes fail (guessing because the filling creates a Mesh, which then can't be filleted etc.):

Why does selecting fill mode "none" ruin the resolution of my curve and what can I do about it? Also open to suggestions of how to rewrite the Geo Nodes instead, but this is the one way I have found works to get what I want...
Some things I've tried include the "Resample Curve" node that indeed gets me resolution back at the cost of a horrible number of vertices and great slowdown---but it also breaks the Bevel modifier for some reason.
EDIT: about this exact breakage of the Bevel modifier, it seems to very weirdly depend on the angles of the vector/free handles that are part of the curve:

(I only get this far by enabling "Limit Radius" in the Fillet Curve node, but it seems that is not enough...)
See this file for one of the actual curves I'm working with:


I don't really understand your issue, and I don't have any None option for the Shape > Fill Mode (it should be Full, Back, Front, Half). Also, without seeing your curve, geometry with the modifiers, ... helping you will be hard.

@Lutzi Fill Mode: none is available when you switch the curve from 3D to 2D.

I honestly can't understand what exactly you're trying to do here (it may be an XY problem), but your question about why Fillet Curve works so strangely here is easily explained:
Fillet Curve works with the individual points of a curve.
However, since you are using a Bézier circle as the base, and this only consists of a total of four points (the resolution describes the steps between these four points), you get a square after using Fillet Curve because the resolution between the points is lost.
To solve the problem, you would simply have to resample the Bézie curve beforehand.
Something like this:

(Blender 4.1.1+)

Update
It has now been clarified in the comments that the underlying geometry is somewhat more complicated in this specific case.
In this particular case, the Fillet Curve node causes the problem that all points of the curve are processed, which means that the bevel modifier no longer works correctly because the points at the end along the entire curve are too close together.
However, this problem can be solved in this use case by only passing a value for the radius to the Fillet Curve node if the angle between two points exceeds a certain value. In this way, for example, all right-angled corners can be rounded and all other points can remain unprocessed.
Something like this:

I determine the angle between two points with the following node group:

Even if it was not part of the question asked, in this case the bevel modifier should also be restricted to the upper edge of the extruded mesh. You can achieve this by using Store Named Attribute to create the selection "Top" with the identifier "bevel_weight_edge" and selecting the value "Weight" as the Limit Method in the bevel modifier.


Thanks!! I went and gave the resampling another try, but couldn't get the Bevel to show up like I originally said. So why did it work in your example? The answer seems to be that I have vector/free handles at angles around 90deg that break the Bezel. What's weirder is that its not that these angles don't work per se, but one has to fiddle with them to find like the exact values that work within a sea of not working ones? Adding pictures to illustrate to the main post.

@Sabrina Please share your blend file via https://blend-exchange.com ...I'm still not quite clear what exactly your goal is. There may be another solution for what you are trying to do.

Uploaded to https://blend-exchange.com/b/XPP5qGP9/. It's basically my shape and the nodes you shared. What I want is to have my curve with some vector handles and some aligned ones. The mesh I want to define from this is essentially one thats extruded and then rounded in all directions---hence the filleting to do it in the 2D plane, and then after extruding the Beveling to get rounding along the remaining axis if that makes sense. Essentially I want things to look like your file :) But with sharp angles in the underlying curve that seem to break things.

@Sabrina Ah, all right, in this case it is a little more complicated, as the Fillet Curve node also processes points that should not be rounded off in this case. I have modified the answer accordingly. Let me know if that works for you.

Whoa! I will admit, I only somewhat grasp what's going on here (mostly what exactly the angle is and why having it be bigger than the 80 is what we want to fillet), but I will absolutely take it! Thank you so much for putting in all this effort, this is amazing stuff :)
